# Can this code be converted into a single linq statement?

Tags: linq

I'm trying to filter a list within a list from an entity framework entity.

I've managed to get the code working however, i'm not convinced it's the cleanest way of achieving the goal.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
        foreach (var n1 in tier.MatchNodes)
        {
            n1.LenderMatchNodes = n1.LenderMatchNodes.Where(x => x.Commission == 0).ToList();
        }
```

Effectively MatchNodes contains a collection of LenderMatchNodes, however I want to return only the nodes where the commission == 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LINQ is supposed to be mutation-free, so not with LINQ. This code is IMHO *extremely* clean, in that it is immediately obvious what's going on here. I 'd leave it be. It would be worth looking at integrating the filtering earlier on in your processing though.

Comment: I don't consider _filtering_ the list of related entities as a mutation...

Comment: @DStanley: The code is mutating the `MatchNodes`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tier.MatchNodes.ToList().ForEach(n1=>n1.LenderMatchNodes = n1.LenderMatchNodes.Where(x => x.Commission == 0).ToList());
```

Comment: Well, Techincally it's one line but I tihnk the _intent_ is to avoid the n+1 probelem (not load the related entities one-by-one)

Answer (score 0):

Try using SelectMany():

```
var result = dataContext.Table<Tier>()
    .Where(some condition to get you the tier)
    .SelectMany(tier => tier.MatchNodes)
    .SelectMany(node => node.LenderMatchNodes)
    .Where(x => x.Commission == 0)
    .ToList();
```

This has the additional benefit of being able to execute it a single SQL query.

If you're goal is to actually update the node list in the database, you can still minimize the number of queries using Include() (assuming you're using EF):

```
var nodes = dataContext.Table<Tier>()
        .Where(some condition to get you the tier)
        .SelectMany(tier => tier.MatchNodes)
        .Include(node => node.LenderMatchNodes) // loads this eagerly
        .ToList();
nodes.ForEach(n => n.LenderMatchNodes = n.LenderMatchNodes.Where(condition));
```